# Excel and Pandas - column should be read as string instead of double/float/int

Tags: python, pandas, excel

I have an excel file with column like below.

```
A
<NA>
<NA>
11234
11222
11456
```

The numbers in above column are stored as text in excel.

When reading this excel to pandas dataframe, the above column gets converted to gets converted to double automatically based on  the data in excel.

Is there a way to not convert this to double when reading through pandas.

I know we can convert this using python. But for my use case it would be better if this is somehow handled in excel itself rather than python.

Is there a way we can manipulate the column in excel and while reading through pandas, the column should be read as string instead of double?

Comment: `read_excel` has a `dtype` parameter.

Comment: can you try? : pvt['AGE'] = pvt['AGE'].astype(str)